# RSpec Version Problem - Rspec Won't Run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I (mistakenly) updated Rspec to version 2.4, but my Gemfile is on version 2.3. I'm now getting the following error message when I try to run Rspec. I believe I need to revert to 2.3 -- any idea how I can do this?

```
/Users/woshea/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:27:in `block in setup': You have already activated rspec-core 2.4.0, but your Gemfile requires rspec-core 2.3.1. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Upgrade your Gemfile to use 2.4, run `gem install`, and it should work.
2. If you want to keep 2.4 on your system but still use 2.3 in your project, run `bundle exec rspec` instead of just `rpsec` and that'll make sure it uses the bundled version.

Comment: I ran "bundle exec rspec" -- it runs, but is not now running my previous tests. Any ideas?

Comment: I just meant to put `bundle exec` before any rspec command. To run all your tests, you'd need to actually do `bundle exec rspec spec` like the other answerer mentioned.

Comment: It looks like this requires spork? I dont have spork installed so I guess I will have to look at installing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch your spec only by bundler

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

or

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

Comment: Is this the complete code or do I need a version in here? I tried running these and I get an error /Users/woshea/rails/sample_app2/spec/spec_helper.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- spork (LoadError)

Comment: it's the complete command. Do a `bundle install` before to fix your spork problem. Or add it on your Gemfile